# Creating a complicated PDF in C#/MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf

This is .NET 4.6/MVC 5. I'm trying to create a rather complicated PDF in C#, but I can't quite figure out a good way to do so.

We use Kendo UI and it has PDF export capabilities ([demos](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/pdf-export/page-layout)), but that requires creating a print layout with HTML/CSS. I was unable to figure out how to use `@page` with images in the header/footer.

We've used [iTextSharp](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp) in the past, but it now requires a very expensive license for commercial use.

[PDFsharp and MigraDoc](http://www.pdfsharp.net) ([API](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Projects/PDFsharp-MigraDoc-GDI)) look nice, but they have almost no documentation and I've been unable to figure out how to use them.

**How can I accomplish the task of creating a PDF in the format of the below screenshot?** I don't need to be spoonfed, just given a general idea. I have no preference for or against any specific method, I just don't know what would work well.

This is the layout I'm attempting to create. The green lines separate the header/body/footer. The header and footer are the same on all pages. The table in the body will display data from a list--it needs to display only what can fit on a page, then move to the next page and the next items in the list.

[image: desired PDF layout]

Comment: How about any report engine like Crystal Reports or something with possibility to export report as PDF file?

Comment: @KamilStachowiak I didn't realize Crystal Reports for Visual Studio is free for commercial use. I'm taking a look now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Essential PDF](http://mvc.syncfusion.com/demos/web/pdf/default) can create complex PDFs with any custom layout. You can also create a template in Word and convert into PDF with your data merged in.

[image: Doc to PDF]

The entire product is available for free and can be used in commercial applications also (if the organization makes less than 1 million USD in annual revenue) through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense).